# Can Firebase Authentication be used as a sign in only?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Can Firebase Authentication be used as a **sign in only**? I'd like to prevent anyone from signing up, and sign up users manually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it via the console.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sign up users manually in Firebase. Once you are logged in, click on the "Authentication" tab in the left panel. When it loads you will see in the upper right corner an option to "ADD USER".

[image]